# Creating DateTime object from DatePicker and TimePicker control

Tags: c#, datetime, windows-phone-7

How to create `DateTime` object from `DatePicker` and `TimePicker` controls in Windows Phone 7?

`DateTime` object constructor accepts only `int` with years, months etc. Is there a smart way to combine date and time and assign it to `DateTime` ?

Comment: Not sure but can't you do like `DateTime dtobj = datepicker.value + new TimeSpan(12, 55, 55);(timepicker value)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use

```
DateTime MyDateTime = ((DateTime) MyDatePicker.Value).Date.Add (((DateTime)MyTimePicker.Value).TimeOfDay);
```